# handle javascripts objects with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

im using JSON to parse some data from MYSQL, but in order to bring all the information in just one call i´m tring to stored everything in JAVASCRIPT OBJECTS(works fine), the problem is i don`t know how can i use with JQUERY to fill in some divs and integrated the info of the objects with different functions. this is how i worked:

```
  // SE DEFINE CADA OBJETO QUE RECIBE INFO DE CADA CAMPO DE BD

  //PLATO
  function PlatoBD(nombreplato , descripcion, caloriasTortilla, precio, ingredientes)   
  {
    this.nombreplato = nombreplato;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.caloriasTortilla = caloriasTortilla;
    this.precio = precio;
        this.ingredientes = function(adiciones , NomPlato){
            peticionBD(adiciones , NomPlato);
        }

  }

  //ADICION
  function AdicionBD(nombreAdicion , calXplato, tipoAdicion)   
  {
    this.nombreAdicion = nombreAdicion;
    this.calXplato = calXplato;
    this.tipoAdicion = tipoAdicion;

  }

  //SE DEFINE LA FUNCION PARA LLAMAR CUALQUIER BASE DE DATOS
  function peticionBD(peticionBDJSON,NomPlato){

    $.post('php/consulta-actualizar-info.php', 
        {"peticionBD" :peticionBDJSON }
        ,
        function(data) {
          var infophpData = $.parseJSON(data);

          if (peticionBDJSON == "menuElpaso") {

            ingred = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < infophpData.length; i++) {
                window["plato_"+infophpData[i]["plato"].replace(' ','_')] = new PlatoBD(infophpData[i]["plato"] , infophpData[i]["descripcion"] , infophpData[i]["caloriasTortilla"] , infophpData[i]["precio"]);
                window["plato_"+infophpData[i]["plato"].replace(' ','_')].ingredientes("adiciones",infophpData[i]["plato"].replace(' ','')) 
            };
          };

          if (peticionBDJSON == "adiciones") {

                    else if (NomPlato =="Burritoveggy")
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < infophpData.length; i++) {
                            window["adicionesPara"+NomPlato+"De"+infophpData[i]["adicion"].replace(" ","_")] = new AdicionBD(infophpData[i]["adicion"] , infophpData[i][NomPlato], infophpData[i]["tipoAdicion"]);
                        };
                    }
                    else if (NomPlato =="Quesadilla")
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < infophpData.length; i++) {
                            window["adicionesPara"+NomPlato+"De"+infophpData[i]["adicion"].replace(" ","_")] = new AdicionBD(infophpData[i]["adicion"] , infophpData[i][NomPlato], infophpData[i]["tipoAdicion"]);
                        };
                    }
            ...
          };


        }).error(
            function(){
            alert('Error al ejecutar la petición');
          },
        'json'
        )

  }


$(document).ready(function($){
  peticionBD("menuElpaso","")
});
```

the response result is(http://wedesign-medellin.com/restaurante-elPaso/objeto-bd-domicilios.html):

`PlatoBD {nombreplato: "Almuerzo", descripcion: "Sopa + elecciones + gaseosa", caloriasTortilla: "250", precio: "14.000", ingredientes: function}`

Comment: jQuery is simply a library that makes JavaScript a little bit easier to use. You can use vanilla JavaScript in jQuery so use standard JS if you are more comfortable doing so with the parts of jQuery that you are ok with.

Comment: you either need to manually parse response data into html or use a template engine script to pass data to

Comment: ok i think it shouldn`t be so confuse, i use it now simple as this: 
NameofObject["firstValueObjec"] 
or dinamically like: 
window["generalName"+ParticularName]["firstValue"]]
but for example i didn`t find the way to count the number of objects, tryng to doit like this:
ObjectFunction.length
Doesn`t work

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.parseJSON(string_object)